# How to replace all images with a certain classname?

Tags: javascript, html, image

So I am attempting to replace all images with another image with a certain classname in order to help with dark/light mode support but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
function darkenclose() {
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
 boxes.forEach(box => {
   box.src = "images/icon/closewin.svg";
 });
function lightenclose() {
 boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
 boxes.forEach(box => {
   box.src = "images/icon/closewin2.svg";
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would think that should work. Have you tried `box.setAttribute('src','images/...')`?

Comment: [More explanation would be greatly appreciated too](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.